# Navbar in bootstrap works on 2 of 4 pages on mobile. Code is the same for all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar on my personal website only works for 2 out of the 4 pages on mobile devices. It works perfectly fine on desktops. I've checked the code a couple of times and I

1. can't seem to find any differences between them, and
2. can't find or figure out a solution.

The link to my webpage is [www.deepshah.co](http://www.deepshah.co) and I will post the HTML code below.

Navbar code for working page:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">DEEP SHAH</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.html">About Me</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="/photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> -->
                <li class="active"><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar code for not working page:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">DEEP SHAH</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li> -->
                    <li class="active"><a href="/photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: This code seems to be the same as you mention, expect you can clearly see there is one more level of indentation going on.   I would suspect there is a larger element wrapper that is causing some pain.

Comment: I will click on the navbar rectangle in the top right corner, and it won't open up the drop-down menu.

Comment: @briansol Can you expand on what you mean by "larger element wrapper"?

Comment: I mean by proper nesting of indents, there is 1 level deeper in your second code base.   It appears you stripped out some code, or above the navbar div, there is another container that is causing the selector to not fire properly.  It is impossible to guess without seeing the whole code.   I would suggest running through w3 validator to make sure you didn't miss some markup.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I deleted some of the redundant CSS code. I had two sets of nav-bar code in my CSS file and when I deleted the ones which I wasn't using anymore, it worked.